# Firebase rule for checking user is in channel is not working with .exists or .val

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hello i am trying to create a firebase rule to check weather or not the user is in the message channel that they are sending a message to. Here is my firebase database structure

[image: firebase channels]

and my rule is

```
    "messages": {
      "$room_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('channels').child($room_id).child('joined').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
        ".validate": "root.child('channels').child($room_id).exists()",
```

the `.validate` rule works, while the `.read` does not. It works if i delete the entry from joined or not, I have also tried replacing `.val() === true` with `.exists()`. I need it to only work if the uid is in joined and set to true.

This is the JS code i am using

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('messages').child(this.selectedChannel);
itemsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        this.messages = Object.entries((data || {})).map(m => {return {id: m[0], user: m[1].user, message: m[1].message}});
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the code that shows the operation tht doesn't work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay done

Comment: This code doesn't *read* any data, does it? The `.read` rule will only be evaluated for operations that read data from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry posted wrong code, i uploaded now

Comment: Hmmm.... at first glance this code looks fine. Can you add a `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, this.selectedChannel)` right above the query, and then update your quesdtion to include both the updated code, and its output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, usually, the approach used is to set values for variables - for chat rooms applications, usually the variables used are `user`, `timestamp` of access and `room_id` - so you can validate if they are not empty and add the message altogheter. In your case, you will be using a third different variable to the `timestamp`, when validating.

Considering that, I believe a good configuration for your verification would be the following - **this code is untested and you will need to modify more it for your usage, but I believe it's a good starting point, as a basic model for you**.

```
".read": "root.child('members/'+$room_id+'/'+auth.uid+joined).exists() && !data.exists() && newData.exists()",
// the object to write must have a name, message, and be in the room
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user', 'message', 'joined'])",
```

As in the above code sample, the validation will be done once it has all the values you want to verify.
A example of this code in full version can be access in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example).

Another example of a simple chat room with Firebase that I would recommend you to access, it's in this following repository: [katowulf/gist:4741111](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/4741111)

Let me know if the information helped you!